# clear blade laravel for render new response ajax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to use the same blade to return a response from ajax.

In my first controller function I return a view with data:

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = (object) array(
        'title' => trans('web.blog_title'),
        'description' => trans('web.blog_header_info'),
    );
    
    $posts = \DB::table('blogs')->paginate(3);
    
    return view('web.blog')->with('data', $data)->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

But now I'm doing a search with ajax and I want to use the same blade template for the response.

My second function that should render my response is:

```php
public function getLocalNews($restaurant_id) {
    $data = (object) array(
        'title' => trans('web.blog_title'),
        'description' => trans('web.blog_header_info'),
    );
    
    $news = Blog::query()->where('restaurant_id', '=', $restaurant_id)->paginate(3);
    
    return view('web.blog')->with('data', $data)->with('posts', $news);
}
```

but it doesn't do anything...

ajax:

```js
$("#submit_btn_blog_res").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
            
    var form = $('#searchRestaurant');
    
    $(this).find('input').removeClass('is-invalid');
    $(this).find('.error').html('');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "blog/getLocalNews/" + $(".suggest-element").attr('id'),
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: form.data('type'),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $(".post-article").remove();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR){
            var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    
            if (response.errors.name) {
                $(form).find('input[name="name"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.name-error').html(response.errors.name);
            } else if (response.errors.email) {
                $(form).find('input[name="email"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.email-error').html(response.errors.email);
            } else if (response.errors.phone) {
                $(form).find('input[name="phone"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.phone-error').html(response.errors.phone);
            } else if (response.errors.comments) {
                $(form).find('input[name="comments"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.comments-error').html(response.errors.comments);
            } else if (response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse) {
                $(form).find('input[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.g-recaptcha-response-error').html(response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse);
            }
        }
    });
}); //submit search form restaurant
```

Comment: [`return response()->json()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your response with a `content-type` of `application/json`. Hopefully, laravel has a function as `response()` which do this for you.

```
public function getLocalNews($restaurant_id){
        $data = (object) array(
            'title' => trans('web.blog_title'),
            'description' => trans('web.blog_header_info'),
        );

        $news = Blog::query()->where('restaurant_id', '=', $restaurant_id)->get();

        $response_data = ['data'=>$data, 'posts'=>$news];
        return response()->json($response_data, 200);
    }
```

As said in [laravel helpers functions doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-response) First parameter of `response()` receives the data that you want to be included in the body. If you pass an array, it will be converted to json, and the second parameter is the http status code of the response.

**Notice**: If you want to send your results with pagination. You can use [laravel api resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#pagination).

**Update**: Use your ajax to add new received data to your html.

```
success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    $('#desired-element-for-data').html('');
    $.each(response.data, function(item){
        html1 += '<p>item</p>';
    });

    $('#desired-element-for-posts').html('');
    $.each(response.posts, function(item){
        html2 += '<p>item</p>';
    });

    $('#desired-element-for-data').html(html1);
    $('#desired-element-for-posts').html(html2);

    $(".post-article").remove();
},
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i don´t understan how i can pass my data to my blade, i can sow it in webbrowser console, but i don´t know how pass this data into blade.

Comment: Do you use jquery for your ajax requests?

Comment: @daviserraalonso I updated the answer to include a sample ajax for you.